# Android-is there seperate header and footer for app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new to android app designing. Is there any idea to maintain centralized code for header and footer as we do in web app.

Next doubt is, when i use multiple linear layout its show error as

> The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Please give me some suggestion, Thanks in advance.
My xml code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="#FF6347"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/name" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/mobile_number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done_button"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done_button"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: seems like you don't know what is an XML ... your XML is not valid http://validator.w3.org

Comment: where do you want the third button to be placed?

Answer (score 0):

like this will be valid , but i don t understand how do you want to arrange the buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="180dp" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="#FF6347"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="2dp"
       >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="2dp"
         />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
           />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```